# Find the total gain from the following Signal Flow Graph

Tags: signal, control-system, transfer-function, gain

[image: .]The signal flow graph for a system is given in the figure. Find resultant gain.

Comment: Apply Mason's formula. There are two forward paths and 4 loops and  two non touching loops

Comment: While Sam Mason's paper, [Feedback Theory -- Further Properties of Signal Flow Graphs](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/4778/RLE-TR-303-15342712.pdf;jsessionid=3C1EA4B25481C494723BE1DB02B6C2CF?sequence=1), is an excellent read, I still find it so much easier to just label each signal and write down the set of simultaneous equations. That's simple, it's hard to make mistakes, it works, and it relies upon prosaic theory, widely taught and used (no need to drill and remember yet another set of tools.)

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Is the answer 44/9.

Comment: @Modulus I can't read the "find gain" fraction. The numerator is obvious (\$c\$.) But what's the denominator there? Is it the input node at the far left? Or something else?

Comment: The fraction is C(s)/R(s), to be clearer !

Comment: @Modulus Do you have any idea at all how you might write a set of simultaneous equations for this? (It's pretty easy.) Do you have any experiences to rely on? (Or is this a problem "totally out of the blue" for you?)

Comment: Sorry, as of now have been solving only using signal flow graphs. Can you tell me where to read simultaneous equations method ?

Comment: @Modulus I'll provide an answer for using simultaneous equations. It's easy and more prosaic. (If you are supposed to apply Mason's gain formula then you should read the paper at the link I provided. I won't provide an answer using that approach, directly.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a far more complex case, just to show how easy this all is using simultaneous equations:

[image]

(I picked the above problem from [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/control_systems/control_systems_masons_gain_formula.htm).)

Using [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) as my solver, enter the following lines:

```
var('ga gb gc gd ge gf gg gh gi gj n2 n3 n4 n5 n6')
s2 = Eq( n2, ga*n1 + gj*n3 )
s3 = Eq( n3, gb*n2 + gh*n5 )
s4 = Eq( n4, gc*n3 + gi*n5 )
s5 = Eq( n5, gd*n4 + gg*n3 + gf*n5 )
s6 = Eq( n6, ge*n5 )
ans = solve( [s2,s3,s4,s5,s6], [n2,n3,n4,n5,n6] )

pprint( ans[n6]/n1 )

                      ga⋅gb⋅ge⋅(gc⋅gd + gg)
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
gb⋅gd⋅gi⋅gj + gb⋅gf⋅gj - gb⋅gj - gc⋅gd⋅gh - gd⋅gi - gf - gg⋅gh + 1
```

Please take a moment and go above to read each of the equations I set up (\$s_2\$, etc.) You should *easily* be able to see how it is that I wrote those out. It's very easy. For example, node 2 (\$n_2\$) only has two terms added together: \$N_1\cdot A\$ and \$N_3\cdot J\$. You should easily see why I wrote out the equation for \$s_2\$ in the way I did.

The solver does the rest. And the answer is correct. (You can verify it by simply looking at the site I mentioned earlier. Please note that they did ***not*** use simultaneous equations to arrive at their solution. They used Mason's gain formula. But their solution is exactly the same one that I arrived at using a very simple and very well-known approach.)

Now, given the above process I've laid out, do you think you can write the appropriate equations for your case? (It's fewer equations and simpler to do.) The result, if you get it correctly handled, will have the numerator you mentioned (**44**) but not the same denominator value you mentioned.

(If you still need help, I'll add more details directly targeting your solution.)

---

In your circumstance, you need to label your nodes (you haven't done that, yet.) I believe your gains are the finite values shown on your diagram. So you can just use those values, directly, in your equation set up.

For example, I've labeled two of your nodes below:

[image]

The equation for it is: \$X_1=1\cdot R_s - 1\cdot X_2=R_s-X_2\$. You should be able to develop the equations for all of \$X_1\$ through \$X_4\$ (\$C_s=X_4\$, so that's trivial.)

Comment: More help required. I don't know sympy. I don't know where are the equation kindly explain for a layman.

Comment: @Modulus You don't need to know sympy. The text is relatively readable without knowing the precise details of the language. If you know anything about simultaneous equation solutions, it should be relatively understandable how each equation was set up. And if you have ever performed a simultaneous equation solution of this kind, you either have the software tools available or else you know how to use [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), by hand. Is this completely obscure to you?

Comment: Quite obscure, however Cramer's rule I have read long time back. Lemme revise.

Comment: @Modulus I hadn't realized you were doing self-study, earlier. Your other question clarifies this. If you write back with more questions about how to proceed, I'll add more to the answer I've written here.

Comment: In fact it's kind of urgent.......However all the qns asked or to be asked in future will figure here only after sincere efforts have not yielded an answer and my solution will be right there.

Comment: @Modulus I'm not sure I understand what your goal is. I can certainly just tell you the answer. But I felt you were interested in learning enough to work this out for yourself. I didn't want to take that away from you. What's your actual goal?

Comment: Actual goal is gaining insight into solving these kind of problems. Only

Comment: @Modulus The gain should be \$\frac{44}{23}\$, I believe. See if you can find this same value. Just note that: \$x_1=R_s-x_2\$, \$x_2=2\cdot x_1-x_3\$, \$x_3=3\cdot x_2-x_4\$, and \$x_4=4\cdot x_3+5\cdot x_1\$. And, of course, \$C_s=x_4\$. If you work through the algebra involved, I believe you'll get the same result as I did.