# Transfer function using signal flow graph problem

Tags: control-system, transfer-function

Determine the system transfer function for the following signal-flow diagram of figure

[image]

I have shown my attempt of solving this problem. Can anyone tell me whether I did this problem properly?

Comment: Why can't you ask your teacher or check the answer in the book? ["Can you check my work?" Is not a valid question.](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6166/72179)

Comment: You might look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/447153/38098).